# Слитное написание слова «неочевидное»

Tags: слитно-раздельно, частица-не

В предложении:

> Глядя на кучу данных может быть **не очевидным** то, что вообще с ними может происходить или кому они могут быть нужны

Чуть больше контекста:

> Мы можем разложить данные в одни классы, а методы в другие и это тоже будет работать и будет даже более модульно. Но все равно может нести ряд минусов. Глядя на кучу данных может быть **не очевидным** то, что вообще с ними может происходить или кому они могут быть нужны. Тоже самое и с кучей методов.

правильно ли написано `не очевидным`?

Comment: Содержание предложения неясно, поэтому редактирование его может  исказить смысл сказанного. Они - это кто/что? Может быть, речь идет об этих никому не нужных данных. Поэтому предлагаю вопрос временно  закрыть и отправить на доработку.

Comment: @Arina, да, добавил чуть больше контекста

Answer (score 3):

Предложение нуждается в правке, в нём допущена ошибка в использовании оборота ГЛЯДЯ НА КУЧУ ДАННЫХ. С ним же связан стилистический недочёт. Отвечу на вопрос с учётом сказанного.

НЕ в слове НЕОЧЕВИДНЫМ пишем слитно, если прилагательное можно заменить синонимом без НЕ. При этом возможно использование наречия ВЕСЬМА:

*Если учесть большое количество данных, может быть (весьма) неочевидным (син. завуалированным, скрытым, сомнительным) то, что вообще с ними может происходить или кому они могут быть нужны.*

Если же высказывание по значению близко к ВОВСЕ НЕ ОЧЕВИДНЫМ, то НЕ надо писать отдельно:

*Если учесть большое количество данных, может быть (вовсе) не очевидным то, что вообще с ними может происходить или кому они могут быть нужны.*

Comment: Я бы заменил ИЛИ на И. Смысл таков: не()очевидно А и Б.

Comment: Спасибо! Кажется замена на `Если учесть большое количество данных` не совсем подходит, посмотрите, пожалуйста, обновлённый вопрос

Comment: Вариантов замены может быть много, это лишь один, может быть не самый удачный. "Кучу" надо убирать однозначно, это разговорный стиль.

Answer (score 1):

противопоставление не подразумевается, значит, слитно

Comment: Почитайте другие ответы, другие вопросы. Почувствуйте разницу.

Answer (score 1):

Мы можем разложить данные в одни классы, а методы в другие, и это тоже будет работать и будет даже более модульно. Но все равно может нести ряд минусов. **При такой куче данных может быть не очевидным то**, что вообще с ними может происходить или кому они могут быть нужны. То же самое и с кучей методов.

**Пояснение**

1) Деепричастный оборот заменен падежной формой (причина: несочетаемость со сказуемым).

2) Здесь скорее **отрицание**, связанное с возможной отсутствием очевидности, поэтому лучше выбрать раздельное  написание (он вообще чаще встречается и поэтому привычнее выглядит).  В то же время по смыслу эти формы (слитная и раздельная) мало отличаются друг от друга, поэтому возможно авторское решение.

**Примеры**:

Она не только не спешит себя прояснить, а наоборот, ее суть, неуловимая хитрость, выкрадывает захват из явности, **делает его не очевидным.** [В. В. Бибихин. Свое, собственное (1994)]

Не хватает только Новой Зеландии, которую **по неочевидным причинам** заменили Норвегией.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ  (о разговорном стиле)**

**Это не книжная речь**. Весь текстовый отрывок написан в особом стиле, который можно назвать разговором на научную тему. Это общение между людьми, которые знают, о чем говорят, отсюда разговорные выражения и упрощенный синтаксис. Соответственно, менять в отдельности здесь **ничего не нужно**. Если информация будет оформляться книжным текстом, нужно **менять весь стиль.**

Comment: Даже в разговорном стиле нужно выражать свою мысль правильно. Есть смысловая разница между "не очевидно А и Б" и "не очевидно А или Б". В нашем предложении требуется И, а стоит ИЛИ.

Comment: Думаю, что здесь больше подходит именно союз ИЛИ, так как нет жесткой связи между А и Б. Может быть, не очевидно А, а может быть, Б, хотя А + Б тоже не исключается.

Comment: То есть Вы предполагаете, что автор имел в виду "не очевидно А или не очевидно Б". А по-моему там логичнее "не очевидно А и не очевидно Б"

Comment: Конечно, нужно у автора спросить, но по-моему здесь говорится о вопросах, которые МОГУТ возникнуть: один, иди другой, или оба вместе.

Comment: Допустим, следуя вашей мысли, изменим предложение так: *При такой куче данных могут возникнуть вопросы о том, что вообще с ними может происходить И кому они могут быть нужны.* Может возникнуть один вопрос, или другой, или оба вместе, но союз ИЛИ здесь неуместен. Для того, чтобы поставить ИЛИ, нужно написать по-другому: *вопросы о том, что вообще с ними может происходить, ИЛИ о том,  кому они могут быть нужны*

Comment: Оба варианта возможны, одиночные союзы И/ИЛИ пишутся по одним правилам. У Розенталя: Между однородными придаточными частями сложноподчиненного предложения, связанными неповторяющимися союзами (соединительными или разделительными) запятая не ставится. Варианты такие: указательное местоименное слово может повторяться, а может не повторяться. Пример: Эти данные свидетельствуют о том, что  имущество населения изношено почти наполовину и в ближайшие годы следует ожидать массового выбытия товаров длительного пользования.